# How can I subscribe to Weekly Shonen Jump outside Japan?

Tags: shonen-jump

Do anyone know how to get a Weekly Shonen Jump subscription in Europe?

Comment: Have you tried looking at their website? http://shonenjump.viz.com/international-wsj-app

Comment: @кяαzєя that link seems dead. The new link that works for me is https://www.viz.com/shonenjump

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Viz Media](https://www.viz.com/shonenjump)! This is a Japanese-American company that sells dozens of manga magazines in many countries and they are the company publishing the Weekly Shonen Jump.

They also have a [European subsidiary](http://forums.arlongpark.net/showthread.php?t=39443) for, I believe, UK and Ireland. However, I believe you can't have a paper version in another country than Japan. You'll have to read it on your computer or phone.